# How to export a variable to make ti dynamic using React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-observable

I have a problem because I want to use a variable to make a url dynamic

I have this Epic called usersEpic.ts that brings the user info by ID

```
  export const readUserById = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(READ_USER),
    mergeMap((action: { type: string; payload: any }) => {
      return requestEpic({
        actionType: READ_USER_SUCCESS,
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/users/1`, //HERE I NEED TO IMPORT THE ID TO BE DYNAMIC
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${state$.value.accountReducer.activeUserAccount.accessToken}`
        },
      })
    })
  )
```

I have another page called interns.tsx that render all the users with a map.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { LOAD_USERS } from "../../components/store/reducers/usersReducer";

export default function Users() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.usersReducer.users);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USERS,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="dataText">Interns</h1>
        <div className="center-item">
          <div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Number</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {users.map((item) => {
                let id = item.id;
                const url = `http://localhost:3001/users/${id}`;
                return (
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{item.document}</td>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td>{item.lastname}</td>
                      <td>{item.email}</td>
                      <td className="icons">
                        <a href={url}>
                          <i className="fas fa-info-circle icon"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href={url}>
                          <i className="fas fa-user-edit icon"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/users/readUser">
                          <i className="fas fa-power-off icon green"></i>
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                );
              })}
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to export the **id = item.id** variable from interns.tsx to usersEpic.ts to use it as a dynamic value.

If anyone can help me thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of "dynamic" you want to get the user id from the `action.payload`.  Though I'm confused by this code because it seems like all users are already fetched by the `LOAD_USERS` action.

Comment: Yes all the users are loaded by LOAD_USERS but I want to click on the <a href={url}><i className="fas fa-info-circle icon"></i></a> and get the info about that particular User.

Comment: Ohhhh I misunderstood this a fetch action but it's actually a navigation action.  How are you handing navigation right now?  It seems like you should just go to that page through react-router-dom or similar.

Comment: Yes Im using react router to navigate.

Comment: Ok so replace `<a href={url}>` with `<Link to={\`/users/${id}\`}>`.  Let the user page handle its own actions.

Comment: @Frank I am less familiar with https://redux-observable.js.org/, but I tried to answer your question. Let me know if it doesn't work, or you are looking for something else.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I think you are right about replacing the `a` with `Link`. That should have solved the problem.

Comment: @AjeetShah yeah your answer was my first thought and it's the correct answer to the question that is asked.  But I don't think they are asking the right question because handling it through an epic is really unnecessary.

Comment: @LindaPaiste and AjeetShah thank you sou much for the help I make it work with the solution of AjeetShah Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a click handler to which you can pass the `id` and dispatch the action with type `READ_USER` and payload having the `id`:

```
function handleUserClick(id) {
  dispatch({
    type: READ_USER,
    payload: { id }, // passing the id in payload
  });
}

...

<td className="icons">
  <i
    className="fas fa-info-circle icon"
    onClick={() => handleUserClick(item.id)}
  ></i>
...
```

And get the `id` form the payload in epic:

```
export const readUserById = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(READ_USER),
    mergeMap((action: { type: string; payload: any }) => {
      return requestEpic({
        actionType: READ_USER_SUCCESS,
        method: "GET",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/users/${action.payload.id}`, // HERE, reading the id from the payload
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${state$.value.accountReducer.activeUserAccount.accessToken}`,
        },
      });
    })
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much I make it work with this!